# Pandas applymap method with passing column name as parameter

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, python-applymap

I want to use applymap method with a little bit complex function in the dataset below.

```
 value1 value2 value3 value4 value5  people

   147    119     69     92    106   533.0
    31     20     12     14     26   103.0
    37     22     24     18     19   120.0
    10     13      7     13     10    53.0
    38     48     18     30     27   161.0
   401    409    168    354    338  1670.0
   109     92     55     82     69   407.0
     5      9      7     11      9    41.0
    44     36     21     48     28   177.0
    59     40     19     38     27   183.0
     8      9      1      7     10    35.0
```

People column represents sum of the value columns. I want to replace the value numbers with percentages of them.
For example: In first row value1 is 147 and sum of the values in first row is 533. I want to replace 147 with (147/533)*100

I think it looks like this. but i couldn't make it work.

```
df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'] = df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'].applymap(lambda x: (x / df['people'])*100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is used for process each value of `DataFrame` elemenwise.

Better is use vectorized solution with [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'] = df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'].div(df['people'], axis=0) * 100
print (df)
       value1     value2     value3     value4     value5  people
0   27.579737  22.326454  12.945591  17.260788  19.887430   533.0
1   30.097087  19.417476  11.650485  13.592233  25.242718   103.0
2   30.833333  18.333333  20.000000  15.000000  15.833333   120.0
3   18.867925  24.528302  13.207547  24.528302  18.867925    53.0
4   23.602484  29.813665  11.180124  18.633540  16.770186   161.0
5   24.011976  24.491018  10.059880  21.197605  20.239521  1670.0
6   26.781327  22.604423  13.513514  20.147420  16.953317   407.0
7   12.195122  21.951220  17.073171  26.829268  21.951220    41.0
8   24.858757  20.338983  11.864407  27.118644  15.819209   177.0
9   32.240437  21.857923  10.382514  20.765027  14.754098   183.0
10  22.857143  25.714286   2.857143  20.000000  28.571429    35.0
```

---

Another `numpy` solution with broadcasting:

```
df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'] = (df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'].values / 
                                     df['people'].values[:, None] * 100)
print (df)
       value1     value2     value3     value4     value5  people
0   27.579737  22.326454  12.945591  17.260788  19.887430   533.0
1   30.097087  19.417476  11.650485  13.592233  25.242718   103.0
2   30.833333  18.333333  20.000000  15.000000  15.833333   120.0
3   18.867925  24.528302  13.207547  24.528302  18.867925    53.0
4   23.602484  29.813665  11.180124  18.633540  16.770186   161.0
5   24.011976  24.491018  10.059880  21.197605  20.239521  1670.0
6   26.781327  22.604423  13.513514  20.147420  16.953317   407.0
7   12.195122  21.951220  17.073171  26.829268  21.951220    41.0
8   24.858757  20.338983  11.864407  27.118644  15.819209   177.0
9   32.240437  21.857923  10.382514  20.765027  14.754098   183.0
10  22.857143  25.714286   2.857143  20.000000  28.571429    35.0
```

---

If want something similar like `applymap` is possible use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), but solutions above are faster:

```
df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'] = )df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5']
                                   .apply(lambda x: (x / df['people'])*100))
print (df)
       value1     value2     value3     value4     value5  people
0   27.579737  22.326454  12.945591  17.260788  19.887430   533.0
1   30.097087  19.417476  11.650485  13.592233  25.242718   103.0
2   30.833333  18.333333  20.000000  15.000000  15.833333   120.0
3   18.867925  24.528302  13.207547  24.528302  18.867925    53.0
4   23.602484  29.813665  11.180124  18.633540  16.770186   161.0
5   24.011976  24.491018  10.059880  21.197605  20.239521  1670.0
6   26.781327  22.604423  13.513514  20.147420  16.953317   407.0
7   12.195122  21.951220  17.073171  26.829268  21.951220    41.0
8   24.858757  20.338983  11.864407  27.118644  15.819209   177.0
9   32.240437  21.857923  10.382514  20.765027  14.754098   183.0
10  22.857143  25.714286   2.857143  20.000000  28.571429    35.0
```

Comment: In vectorized implementation, i have get the `mask = notna(xrav) & notna(yrav)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (405,) (81,)`

Comment: @Tahtakafa is slice same in both sides `'value1':'value5'` ?

Comment: Now i get the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'` with Numpy implementation. I think people and value columns are different types.

Comment: @Tahtakafa - hmm, it is another problem. Is possible convert decimal columns to `integer`s ? `df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'] = df.loc[:, 'value1':'value5'].astype(int).div(df['people'], axis=0) * 100` ?

Comment: Thank you @jezrael I think i got it.

Comment: @Tahtakafa - Problem was pandas not native support `Decimal`, so weird errors.